# Any website offer the same service as Slice host for Windows Server?

Tags: windows, hosting, dedicated-hosting

Is it possible to get Windows Server 2003 hosted with options similar to Linux hosting at Slicehost and Linode? Need to set up a test server for a few months to see if its feasible to create a plugin for MS Exchange Server.

I'd needs some for of graphical remote access and naturally keep costs as low as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for Windows VPS and you will find many. 
You can find plans under $30/month. 
I remember VPSLand has such plans.

Another idea would be to use Amazon EC2. It's on-demand so you are billed by the hour of usage. You can fire up your instance when you need it and shut it down when you are done with it.